PowerBI Embed report with AAS datasource in other tenant
We are trying to create a simple webpage (in React) that shows a PowerBI report with PowerBI embed.
The datasource for the PowerBI report is located in a different Azure Tenant. (AAS datasource)
For this purpose we created a multi-tenant service principal.
To get the embedtoken we are using an Azure Function that uses the ClientID and ClientSecret to logon. The code is based on the following sample code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-azure-analysis-services?tabs=service-principal-token
But we keep running into the issue below

Has anybody tried this case before? (As a temporary workaround we are going to use a Master/Service User)
What did we already try?

I tried the same scenario with one of the Sample embed applications (the .net core one) on GitHub (https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/.NET%20Core/Embed%20for%20your%20customers) But same issue
We can Embed a report with a datasource in a single tenant
We can connect to AAS (via SSMS) with the Service Principal


The error "Unable to connect to the data model" commonly happens when access is granted in Azure Analysis Services but not in the associated database.
Could you confirm if you have granted access to the database as well?
Please refer to the following documenation - Solved: Unable to Connect to Data model Azure - Power bi - Microsoft Fabric Community

@Madhav yes, that was done already

I run a Power BI saas app called Displagent, and I'm wondering the same thing now as one of my customers has this issue. I'm trying to figure this out now, but my guess is that a Power BI report cannot be embedded unless the origin tenant has an Azure App Service or Enterprise Application (Azure terms for those who do not know) that allows embedding to happen. So even if the tenant that a dataset was shared to has embed permissions, I think the origin tenant needs embed permissions, too.
